# How to adjust additional cost from wash sale transaction on form 8949

Tags: united-states, taxes, capital-loss, wash-sale

I have a few wash sale transactions in 2014.

At the year end, I hold no position and I'm in the US.

Question is when can I add loss from wash sale back to cost (box e)?

Jan 2015: No short sale nor PUT buying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you sell your next position, assuming it is not a wash.

The fact that you have no positions at the end of the year is meaningless. Wash sale rules talk about repurchasing same or similar asset within 30 days before or after the sale at loss. It doesn't matter if you sell on December 31st and buy back on January 1st.

Comment: say I have no transaction on Jan 2015 too.
Can I adjust my cost to correspond trades?

Comment: +1 for the fact that wash does not end on 12/31. A point many miss.

Comment: @TLJ then how is it a wash sale?

Comment: @littleadv because I see mark as W on 1099B from my broker.
Long story short, I was trying to do day trading. So there are win and lost transactions interleaving during dec 2014. I did bought some on Jan 2015, but the number of shares is far less that what were marked as wash in Dec 2014

Comment: @TLJ so when you sell those you bought in Jan 2015 you can add the disallowed loss as adjustment to basis.

Comment: @littleadv but those that bought on Jan15 was a common stock. I have wash sale on PUT(short) transaction.

Comment: @TLJ of the same stock?

Comment: @littleadv Yes the one I bought on JAN15 is the same stock. The different is that I long it instead of shorting it. And only 100 shares.

Comment: @TLj so its the same asset? Its a short sale.

Comment: I figured it all out. All I have to do is to add back wash sale lost to cost. Thanks :)